# How to read data from a file into an array of a class

Tags: c++, file-io

This assignment involves making a program that will read in a car agency and its cars(+car information) from a text file.

Specifically I am supposed to read in a car agency name, a car agency zip code, and then a car's year, make, model, its sensors, and its availability.

I'm having a really difficult time reading in the sensors due to the way it looks in the text file with '{' and '}'. Also the max sensors is 3, but there isn't always 3 for each car.

I've created Sensor, Car, and Agency classes.

The input file (HighTechAgency.txt):

```
Enterprise 89502
2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 {gps} 1
2012 Honda CRV 85.10 {camera lidar} 0
2011 Toyota Rav4 65.02 {} 0
2009 Dodge Neon 45.25 {camera lidar radar} 1
2015 Ford Fusion 90.89 {lidar} 0
```

Sensor.h:

```
#ifndef SENSOR_H
#define SENSOR_H
#define MAX_CHAR 256

class Sensor{
    char type [MAX_CHAR];
    float extracost;
    static int gps_cnt, camera_cnt, lidar_cnt, radar_cnt;
public:
    Sensor();
    Sensor(char[]);
    Sensor(Sensor & other); 
    char* getType();
    float getExtraCost();
    void setType(char[]);
    void setExtraCost(char[]);
    void sensorCnt(char[]);
    static int getGPSCnt();
    static int getCameraCnt();
    static int getLidarCnt();
    static int getRadarCnt();
    static void resetGPSCnt();
    static void resetCameraCnt();
    static void resetLidarCnt();
    static void resetRadarCnt();
};

bool operator==(Sensor & sensor1, Sensor & sensor2);

#endif
```

Sensor.cpp:

```
#include "Sensor.h"
#include "myStrings.h"

int Sensor::gps_cnt = 0;
int Sensor::camera_cnt = 0;
int Sensor::lidar_cnt = 0;
int Sensor::radar_cnt = 0;

Sensor::Sensor(){
    type[0] = '\0';
    extracost = 0;
}

Sensor::Sensor(char sensorName[]){
    setType(sensorName);
}

Sensor::Sensor(Sensor & other){ 
    setType(other.type);
}

char* Sensor::getType(){
    return type;
}

float Sensor::getExtraCost(){
    return extracost;
}

void Sensor::setType(char typeSensor[]){
    myStrings::strCpy(type,typeSensor);
    sensorCnt(typeSensor);
    setExtraCost(typeSensor);
}

void Sensor::setExtraCost(char newType[]){
    if(myStrings::strCmp(newType,"gps") == 0){
        extracost = 5;
    }
    if(myStrings::strCmp(newType, "camera") == 0){
        extracost = 10;
    }
    if(myStrings::strCmp(newType, "lidar") == 0){
        extracost = 15;
    }
    if(myStrings::strCmp(newType, "radar") == 0){
        extracost = 20;
    }
    if(myStrings::strCmp(newType, "") == 0){
        extracost = 0;
    }
}

void Sensor::sensorCnt(char sensorType[]){
    if(myStrings::strCmp(sensorType,"gps") == 0){
        gps_cnt++;
    }
    if(myStrings::strCmp(sensorType, "camera") == 0){
        camera_cnt++;
    }
    if(myStrings::strCmp(sensorType, "lidar") == 0){
        lidar_cnt++;
    }
    if(myStrings::strCmp(sensorType, "radar") == 0){
        radar_cnt++;
    }
}

int Sensor::getGPSCnt(){
return gps_cnt;
}

int Sensor::getCameraCnt(){
    return camera_cnt;
}

int Sensor::getLidarCnt(){
    return lidar_cnt;
}

int Sensor::getRadarCnt(){
    return radar_cnt;
}

void Sensor::resetGPSCnt(){
    gps_cnt = 0;
}

void Sensor::resetCameraCnt(){
    camera_cnt = 0;
}

void Sensor::resetLidarCnt(){
    lidar_cnt = 0;
}

void Sensor::resetRadarCnt(){
    radar_cnt = 0;
}

bool operator==(Sensor& sensor1, Sensor& sensor2){
    return (myStrings::strCmp(sensor1.getType(),sensor2.getType()) == 0);
}
```

Car.h:

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H
#define MAX_SENS 3

#include "Sensor.h"

class Car{
    char make[MAX_CHAR];
    char model[MAX_CHAR];
    int year;
    Sensor sensor[MAX_SENS];
    float baseprice, finalprice;
    bool available;
public:
    Car();
    Car(char[], char[], int, float, Sensor[], bool);
    Car(Car & other);
    char* getMake();
    char* getModel();
    int getYear();
    float getBasePrice();
    float getFinalPrice(); 
    bool getAvailable();
    void setMake(char[]);
    void setModel(char[]);
    void setYear(int);
    void setBasePrice(float);
    void setAvailable(bool);
    void updatePrice();
    void print();
    float estimateCost(int);
    void addSensor(Sensor[]);
};

#endif
```

Car.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"
#include "myStrings.h"

Car::Car(){
    make[0] = '\0';
    model[0] = '\0';
    year = 0;
    baseprice = 0;
    finalprice = 0;
    available = false;
}

Car::Car(char newMake[], char newModel[], int newYear, float newBasePrice, Sensor newSensor[], bool newAvailable){
    setMake(newMake);
    setModel(newModel);
    setYear(newYear);
    setBasePrice(newBasePrice);
    setAvailable(newAvailable);
    addSensor(newSensor);
}

Car::Car(Car & other){
    setMake(other.make);
    setModel(other.model);
    setYear(other.year);
    setBasePrice(other.baseprice);
    setAvailable(other.available);
    addSensor(other.sensor);
}

char* Car::getMake(){
    return make;
}

char* Car::getModel(){
    return model;
}

int Car::getYear(){
    return year;
}

float Car::getBasePrice(){
    return baseprice;
}

float Car::getFinalPrice(){
    return finalprice;
}

bool Car::getAvailable(){
    return available;
}

void Car::setMake(char m_make[]){
    myStrings::strCpy(make,m_make);
}

void Car::setModel(char m_model[]){
    myStrings::strCpy(model,m_model);
}

void Car::setYear(int m_year){
    year = m_year;
}

void Car::setBasePrice(float m_baseprice){
    baseprice = m_baseprice;
}

void Car::setAvailable(bool m_available){
    available = m_available;
}

void Car::updatePrice(){
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SENS; i++){
        finalprice += sensor[i].getExtraCost();
    }
    finalprice += baseprice;
}

void Car::print(){
    updatePrice();
    std::cout << year << " " << make << " " << model << ", $" << baseprice << " per day,";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SENS; i++){
        std::cout << " " << sensor[i].getType() << " ";
    }
    std::cout << " Available: " << std::boolalpha << available;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

float Car::estimateCost(int days){
    return (finalprice * days); 
}

void Car::addSensor(Sensor sensorAdd[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SENS; i++){
        char temp[MAX_CHAR];
        myStrings::strCpy(temp,sensorAdd[i].getType());
        sensor[i].setType(temp);
    }
}
```

Agency.h:

```
#ifndef AGENCY_H
#define AGENCY_H
#define MAX_CARS 5

#include "Car.h"

class Agency{
    char name[MAX_CHAR];
    int zipcode;
    Car inventory[MAX_CARS];
public:
    Agency();
    char* getName();
    int getZipcode();
    void setName(char[]);
    void setZipcode(int);
    void readAllData(Car []);
    void printAllData(Car []);
    void printAvailableCars(Car []); 
};

#endif
```

Agency.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Agency.h"
#include "myStrings.h"
#define MAX_LEN 25

Agency::Agency(){
    name[0] = '\0';
    zipcode = 0;
}

char* Agency::getName(){
    return name;
}

int Agency::getZipcode(){
    return zipcode;
}

void Agency::setName(char newName[]){
    myStrings::strCpy(name, newName);
}

void Agency::setZipcode(int newZipcode){
    zipcode = newZipcode;
}

void Agency::readAllData(Car data[]){
    char inputFile[MAX_LEN];
    int tempYear;
    char tempMake[MAX_CHAR];
    char tempModel[MAX_CHAR];
    float tempPrice;
    char tempSensor[MAX_CHAR];
    Sensor sens[MAX_SENS];
    bool tempAvailable;
    std::ifstream inputStream;

    std::cout << "Enter input file name: ";
    std::cin >> inputFile;

    inputStream.open(inputFile);

    if(inputStream.is_open()){

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "*" << inputFile << " has been read.*" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        inputStream >> name >> zipcode;

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CARS; i++){
            inputStream >> tempYear >> tempMake >> tempModel >> tempPrice >> tempSensor >> tempAvailable;

            inventory[i].setYear(tempYear);
            inventory[i].setMake(tempMake);
            inventory[i].setModel(tempModel);
            inventory[i].setBasePrice(tempPrice);

            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SENS; j++){
                sens[j].setType(tempSensor);
                myStrings::strCpy(tempSensor,sens[j].getType());
                inventory[i].addSensor(sens);
            }
        inventory[i].setAvailable(tempAvailable);
        }
    }

if(!inputStream.is_open()){
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << inputFile << std::endl;
    }
}

void Agency::printAllData(Car data[]){
    std::cout << name << " " << zipcode;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CARS; i++){
        inventory[i].print();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void Agency::printAvailableCars(Car data[]){
    std::cout << name << " " << zipcode;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CARS; i++){
        if(inventory[i].getAvailable() == 1){
        std::cout << inventory[i].getYear() << " " << inventory[i].getMake() << " " << inventory[i].getModel() << ", " << "$" << inventory[i].getFinalPrice() << " per day" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std:: endl;    
}
```

Proj4.cpp (driver): (testing reading input for now)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Agency.h"

int main()
{
    Agency data;
    Car cars[9];
    data.readAllData(cars);
    data.printAllData(cars);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what is getting printed to the terminal.

```
Enterprise 89502
2014 Toyota Tacoma, $115.12 per day, {gps}  {gps}  {gps}  Available: true
2012 Honda CRV, $85.1 per day, {camera  {camera  {camera  Available: false
2012 Honda CRV, $85.1 per day, {camera  {camera  {camera  Available: false
2012 Honda CRV, $85.1 per day, {camera  {camera  {camera  Available: false
2012 Honda CRV, $85.1 per day, {camera  {camera  {camera  Available: false
```

But I want is:

```
Enterprise 89502
2014 Toyota Tacoma, $115.12 per day, {gps}  Available: true
2012 Honda CRV, $85.1 per day, {camera  lidar}  Available: false
2011 Toyota Rav4, $65.02 per day, {}  Available: false
2009 Dodge Neon, $45.25 per day, {camera  lidar  radar}  Available: true
2015 Ford Fusion, $90.89 per day, {lidar}  Available: true
```

I know there is a problem where I'm reading my input. Specifically here in the function readAllData in Agency.cpp.

```
void Agency::readAllData(Car data[]){
    char inputFile[MAX_LEN];
    int tempYear;
    char tempMake[MAX_CHAR];
    char tempModel[MAX_CHAR];
    float tempPrice;
    char tempSensor[MAX_CHAR];
    Sensor sens[MAX_SENS];
    bool tempAvailable;
    std::ifstream inputStream;

    std::cout << "Enter input file name: ";
    std::cin >> inputFile;

    inputStream.open(inputFile);

    if(inputStream.is_open()){

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "*" << inputFile << " has been read.*" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        inputStream >> name >> zipcode;

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CARS; i++){
            inputStream >> tempYear >> tempMake >> tempModel >> tempPrice >> tempSensor >> tempAvailable;

            inventory[i].setYear(tempYear);
            inventory[i].setMake(tempMake);
            inventory[i].setModel(tempModel);
            inventory[i].setBasePrice(tempPrice);

            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SENS; j++){
                sens[j].setType(tempSensor);
                myStrings::strCpy(tempSensor,sens[j].getType());
                inventory[i].addSensor(sens);
            }
        inventory[i].setAvailable(tempAvailable);
        }
    }

if(!inputStream.is_open()){
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << inputFile << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I think what's happening is that after it reads the price, it looks for the next set of characters and stores that one "word" into tempSensor.

For the first line:

```
2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 {gps} 1
```

It stores {gps} as tempSensor, and stores it three times.

Hence:

```
2014 Toyota Tacoma, $115.12 per day, {gps}  {gps}  {gps}  Available: true
```

For second line:

```
2012 Honda CRV 85.10 {camera lidar} 0
```

It stores {camera as tempSensor. And stores     {camera three times. Once it hits the whitespace, then it moves to tempAvailable, but it reads in lidar, and since it expects a bool input, then the it messes up the program and that's why it keeps printing the data for Honda.

Hence:

```
2012 Honda CRV, $85.1 per day, {camera  {camera  {camera  Available: false
2012 Honda CRV, $85.1 per day, {camera  {camera  {camera  Available: false
2012 Honda CRV, $85.1 per day, {camera  {camera  {camera  Available: false
2012 Honda CRV, $85.1 per day, {camera  {camera  {camera  Available: false
```

I know that i need to implement something so that it knows to look for 3 words with tempSensor, and to exclude the '{' and '}'.

I'm stuck on how to do that though.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please try to make a minimal example.

Comment: The basic problem is that you are trying to read *words* when your input does not consist of words. The answer (though it ain't easy) is to switch to reading lines and then analyze each line to extract the information you need. Don't expect this to be easy, don't expect any quick fixes from C++ to help you, you're going to have to do the hard work analyzing your input yourself.

Comment: Arrays of `char` can overflow.  Remember to use the `str` functions with char arrays:  `strcat, strcmp, strdup, and strchr`.

Comment: @Chipster Sorry, I thought it would be necessary for readers to understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you used `std::string`, you could use `std::getline(std::cin, car_make, ',')`.

Comment: @john I don't expect a quick fix. I'm just confused how to implement some logic for it to read correctly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Unfortunately, this assignment does not allow the string library. I've created a class for my string functions, which I did not include in the post

Comment: @whiteferrari You read first (I'd recommend read a whole line), you analyze and extract the data second. It's really just a matter of going through the string you've just read character by character looking for the things you are interested in that delineate your data (commas, spaces and {}).

Comment: In your copy constructor, and functions in general, pass by `const` reference unless you intend to modify the parameter.  Most copy constructors pass by constant reference.

Comment: @john would overloading a stream extraction operator work in that case?

Comment: @whiteferrari An extraction operator would work, but so would not using one. It's a side issue, the real issue is the parsing of the input data format.

Comment: @whiteferrari -- *I've created a class for my string functions* -- You should create a string class, not just a class of functions.  Then you could have replaced all of those `char[]` you have now with that class.

Comment: @whiteferrari -- If your input is always the same pattern (year, model1, model2, price, options, number), then this can be easily read in by using `std::istringstream`.  There is no need for all of that parsing logic you have now.

Comment: The request for minimal code is not so much for minimal code (Because what we really want is a simple, complete program that demonstrates the problem and nothing but the problem) but as a tool to force you to more closely examine the problem and remove all of the noise. More often than not, this allows you to find the problem yourself and not need to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `std::istringstream` and not have to use all of the logic you have now to parse the string.  You can even keep all of your character arrays and not need to use `std::string`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 {gps} 1";
    int year;
    char make1[100], make2[100];
    double price;
    char category[100];
    int num;
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    iss >> year >> make1 >> make2 >> price >> category >> num;
    std::cout << year << "\n";
    std::cout << make1 << "\n";
    std::cout << make2 << "\n";
    std::cout << price << "\n";
    std::cout << category  << "\n";
    std::cout << num;    
}
```

Output:

```
2014
Toyota
Tacoma
115.12
{gps}
1
```

---

Here is a full implementation of parsing the data if the curly brace data has more than one element.  It basically sets pointers up within the string, and then feeds that part of the string to the `std::istringstream` to have it do its magic of parsing:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 {gps gps2 gps3} 1";

    // get the position of the braces and save this to a string
    char *pos1 = strchr(s,'{') + 1; // opening brace pointer
    char *pos2 = strchr(s,'}');     // closing brace pointer
    char curly_string[100] = {};
    strncpy(curly_string, pos1, pos2-pos1); // copy everything between these pointers

    // The last value is always located after the closing brace
    char *numpos = pos2 + 1;

    // parse the individual entries
    int year;
    char make1[100], make2[100];
    double price;
    int num;

    // Output the stuff before the curly brace
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    iss >> year >> make1 >> make2 >> price; 
    std::cout << year << "\n";
    std::cout << make1 << "\n";
    std::cout << make2 << "\n";
    std::cout << price << "\n";

    // Output the curly string stuff and its contents
    iss.clear();
    iss.str(curly_string);
    char one_category[100];
    while (iss >> one_category)
        std::cout << one_category << "\n";

    // output the last item (the number)
    iss.clear();
    iss.str(numpos);
    iss >> num;
    std::cout << num;
}
```

Output:

```
2014
Toyota
Tacoma
115.12
gps
gps2
gps3
1
```

Note that this is much easier with `std::string` as the type instead of `char` arrays.  Using the char arrays is wasteful, since I had to declare arrays with 100 entries.

Comment: But what if I wanted to read in {camera lidar radar}? plus I need to be storing these values into a sensor array

Comment: You can use the same technique.  Store in a string, without the starting and ending parentheses, and use `std::istringstream` on that new string.  There is absolutely no need in C++ to be manually parsing simple space delimited data.

Comment: To be more specific, as long as you have a string that has items separated by spaces, use `stringstream` and `>>` to parse.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use character arrays, then use [`istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) with a delimiter:

```
static const unsigned int MAX_LENGTH_MAKE_MODEL = 256;
char make_and_model[MAX_LENGTH_MAKE_MODEL];
inputStream.getline(make_and_model, MAX_LENGTH_MAKE_MODEL, ','];
```

Or you could read in the entire line, then search it and extract substrings:

```
static const unsigned int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 4096;
char line_of_text[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
inputStream.getline(line_of_text, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, '\n');
char * p_comma = strchr(line_of_text, ',');
//...
```

Also research the `strtok` function.